# Отличия анонимного пространства имён от static

Tags: c++, static, namespace

Зачем нужен анонимный `namespace`, если есть ключевое слово `static`, которое также делает символ локальным для его единицы трансляции?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135504/discussion-on-question-by-rsl------static).

Comment: ну вот опять в чат все переместили... ну нечем больше занятся.

Answer (score 0):

В комментариях уже все сказали:

1. Меньше писанины, если статических сущностей нужно много.
2. Действует не только на переменные/функции, но и на классы.

Answer (score 0):

Буду благодарен за любое замечание, я расскажу как сам понимаю...

Просто нужно понять, что имена из пространства имен являются собственностью файла.

Допустим у нас есть файл(не важно, что пример несколько вздорный, главное понять суть):

> ### A.h

```
static char foo() { return '?'; }    
void g();
```

В файле статическая функция уже определена,определение другой функции придется поискать в другом месте. И вот это место:

> A.cpp

```
#include "A.h"
```

раз я подключил `A.h`, то имею  функцию `foo`, которая уникальна для этой единицы трансляции, поэтому тут я не могу определять еще одну такую же функцию. Но безымянное пространство имен дает возможность страховаться от повторного определения, и полагаясь на то, что дальше будет доступен только заголовочный файл, могу записать:

```
/* тут все верно, файл имеет свою собственную  foo*/
namespace {
    char foo() { return 'c'; }  
    void f() { std::cout << foo(); }
}
//static char foo() { return 'R'; } это было бы (ошибкой)повторным определением

void g() {
    f();
}
```

- нужно обращать внимание на то, что нельзя напрямую вызвать `foo` из
  за неоднозначности. Но  само пространство имен есть отдельное
  пространство, где можно обращаться ко всем именам из этого
  пространства, избегая от повторного определения.
- И  `f`  будет вызывать именно `foo` из своего пространства имен.

И если мы где то еще подключим "A.h" и вызовем   `g`  то  компилятор не найдет определение, и делом возьмется компановщик, который найдет определение вызывающее `foo` из безымянного пространства имен. При вызове   `foo`, определение уже известно, и будет вызвана функция заголовочного файла.

P.S. Любой инструмент дает дополнительную возможность. Действуйте по ситуации, и лучше просто избегать от повторения имен и от глобальных объектов.

Comment: Зачем писать `static` в заголовочном файле? Зачем использовать анонимное пространство имён в заголовочном файле? Это ненужные конструкции.

Comment: если поставить `static` в заголовочном файле, то будут три **разных** переменных/функций с одним именем, если, например, будете отдельно компилировать три **cpp** файла с данным хедером. @Stanislav Volodarskiy

Comment: @AlexGlebe, непонятно зачем.

Comment: @Stanislav Volodarskiy, честно говоря, мне тоже не понятно зачем :). (Я в самом начале сказал, что пример есть вздор. Пытался как нибудь разъяснить разницу  static vs namespace